# How do i retrieve POST request data in a controller Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

### **route (routes/account.js)**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express();

var account_controller = require('../controllers/accountController');

router.post('/account/Getuser', account_controller.get_user);
```

### **controller (controllers/accountController.js)**

```
exports.get_user = function (req, res) {

res.send(req.body.name);
};
```

**Postman POST Request body**

```
{
  "name":"Isaac Gyasi Nimako"   
}
```

**Error Report**
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: if you console.log req what does it print ?

Comment: @Dinosan0908 I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
 when i console.log(req.body.name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the body_parser library

var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

here is a very simple example from my GitHub

https://github.com/odaymard/Restful-CRUD-API-with-Node.js-Express/blob/master/server/server.js

Answer (score 0):

you probably don`t have body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
router.use(bodyParser.json())
```